# How does changes() work in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

Example from the home page of rethinkdb.com doesn't work as expected.

```
r.db("test").tableCreate("game");
r.db("test").table("game").indexCreate("score");
r.db("test").table("game").insert({name: "brandon", score: 60});
r.db("test").table("game").insert({name: "leon", score: 80});
r.db("test").table("game").insert({name: "connor", score: 100});
r.db("test").table("game").orderBy({index: "score"}).limit(3).changes()
```

Output:

> { "new_val": { "id":  "c727b9eb-5aaa-46f9-bc09-a6c879cfbfa0" , "name":
>   "brandon" , "score": 60 } } { "new_val": { "id": 
>   "b59d4314-b78c-48c9-8780-0f9d3a6b6887" , "name":  "leon" , "score": 80
>   } } { "new_val": { "id":  "519343b1-cd98-4969-8f07-7bff5d981c81" ,
>   "name":  "connor" , "score": 100 } }

```
r.db("test").table("game").insert({name: "mike", score: 70});
```

Nothing changes but must be changed due to ordering by score.

```
r.db("test").table("game").get("519343b1-cd98-4969-8f07-7bff5d981c81").update({score: 50}) // {name: "connor"}
```

Still nothing..
So why ordered list is not updates as it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the data explorer, unfortunately.  It was fixed in https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4852 and the fix will be pushed out as a point release soon.  Until it's released I'd recommend using one of the drivers to test these queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a failure of the Web interface.  Running these commands from a client driver (I tried it with the JavaScript driver on 2.1.3 and 2.1.4) shows the changes as expected, it's just that the Data Explorer does not update correctly.  If you swap tabs to Table View and back you can see that the cursor has received the changes at the bottom.